# Purpose of homework tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, homework-and-exercises

Recently I saw many homework posts rejected.  I don’t think I’ve ever seen a decently upvoted homework question.  Why is this so?  Perhaps it is better to remove the homework tag altogether?

Comment: Here are [~1700 decently upvoted homework questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aquestion+%5Bhomework-and-exercises%5D+score%3A3+closed%3Ano), in case that changes anything. I'm not claiming that _all_ of these deserve to be decently upvoted and not closed, but at least some (and hopefully most) of them do.

Comment: There have been suggestions for the deletion of the tag, but nothing has come of it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1477/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4022/2451

Comment: @DavidZ those all have less that 5 votes...

Comment: @XcoderX David's search only returns results with score==3. Using a [different search/sort approach](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises?page=13&sort=votes&pagesize=50) I count more than 600 questions in the tag with score >= 5 (but some are closed).   A wizard might be able to write a [query for the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @rob That's strange; for me the search returns results with score 3 or greater. E.g. 4 out of the first 50 results have scores greater than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homework tag has a couple of uses that make it worth keeping.

1. In your profile preferences you can specify tags you wish to ignore - questions with that tag can be greyed out or even completely hidden. That allows people to hide anything tagged as homework.
2. Tagging something as homework will hopefully deter site members from answering it (before it can be closed). This is good since answering homework questions just encourages people to ask them.

Comment: [This recent poll](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/poll-do-you-ignore-the-homework-tag) indicates that relatively few people use the ignore feature (though maybe it just indicates that there was a selection bias that completely scuppered its results).